# getting error object is possibly null in firebase

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am new here in firebase, when i run my function i am getting error :

```
Object is possibly 'null'.

       console.log(snapshot.val());
```

can anyone please look my code and help me to resolve this issue,

here is my code

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';


let serviceAccount = require("../src/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://******.com"
});

let db = admin.database();



exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

exports.groups_list = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    /*let data = {};
    data['status'] =  '1';
    data['groups'] = ["Montreal","Outremont","Saint-Eustache","Sherbrooke"];
    res.send(data);*/
    let groups = db.ref('groups');
    groups.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        const data =  snapshot.val();
        console.log(data);
    });


});
```

Comment: where do u get that error? Which line? Also add your database to the question

Answer (score 0):

As you will see in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on), "if the location (where you attach the listener) has no data, it will be triggered with an empty DataSnapshot (**val() will return null**)".

So you need to check, in your code, if `snapshot.val()` is `null` or not.

---

However, note that using [`on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) in a Cloud Functions is not the recommended way, since a Cloud Function has a finite life time.

You should use the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) method, which "listens for exactly one event of the specified event type, and then stops listening."

```
exports.groups_list = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const groups = db.ref('groups');
    groups.once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
       if (snapshot.val()) {
           console.log(snapshot.val());
           res.send(snapshot.val()) //For example
       } else {
           res.status(204).send('No content'));
       }
    })
    .catch(error => res.status(500).send('....'));

});
```

---

You may be interested by watching the official [video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series), in particular the first video on HTTPS Cloud Functions.

Comment: @NikulPanchal  Hi,did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?